# Get 30000 values from MySQL to Insert into a dropdown using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm loading 30000 values from MySQL and load it a dropdown select. After it load all the values it works ok but it takes to long to fill the dropdown. I'm doing it wrong or should I use another way like autocomplete?

Thanks

HTML code:

```
<div class="control">
  <label for="options" class="short">Fornecedor</label>
  <select id="fornecedor" name="fnd[]" multiple="multiple" class="short">
    <?php  
      $rows = getFornecedores($db);
      foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo html_escape($row['idfornecedor']) ?>"><?php echo html_escape($row['nome']) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

PHP function:

```
function getFornecedores($db){
   $query = " 
    SELECT 
     idfornecedor, nome
    FROM
     fornecedor 
    ORDER BY
     nome
   "; 

   try 
   { 
      $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
      $stmt->execute(); 
   } 
   catch(PDOException $ex) 
   {  
      die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
   }

   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
   return $rows;
}
```

Comment: Use autocomplete / autosuggest.

Comment: You should definitely use autocomplete. 
No user could use this dropdown.

Comment: Yes autocomplete is one good way to go specially with 30k items.

Comment: Your drop down list is likely to be well over 1mb in size which will take a noticeable time to download on even a reasonable speed connection. An ajax based auto complete maybe a good solution, or simpler to code but less effective split up the drop down (ie, if you are selecting people, first have a drop down to select the office the person you want is based at, then another drop down for the person)

Comment: 30k entries in a single select box? No way. I get annoyed when there's a few hundred options to pick from. You need something more user-friendly than a select box for this. Some kind of ajax-driven autocomplete feature, or may be multiple select boxes to pick a category/subcategory/item? Or a few other possibilities... Either way, so need *something* other than the solution you're trying.

Answer (score 3):

Loading 30K elements into a dropdown doesn't really make sense for the user. Do you really expect a user to find anything in such a box? Either try to give some hints or use an automcomplete feature.